# Autofill script doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, authentication, autofill

Previously, user Robin (thank you) helped me to solve some typing mistakes on my code. Anyway, when I click on the button to make the code working, it doesn't do anything.

Where are my mistakes? Thank you very much.

Here are the codes:

**Manifest.json**

```
{  
"name": "Bwin pages",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Open Bwin pages",
"background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
"browser_action": {"default_icon": "icon.gif"},
"permissions": ["tabs","activeTab","https://www.bwin.com"],
"content_scripts": [{
"matches": ["https://www.bwin.com/"],
"js": ["autofill.js"]
                   }],
"run_at": "document_end",
"all_frames": true

}
```

**Background.js**

```
console.log("Background.js Started .. "); 
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'autofill.js'});
console.log("Script Executed .. "); 
});
```

**Autofill.js**

```
console.log("Autofill.js Started .. "); 
var myUsername = "aaa";
var myPassword = "bbb";

var loginField = document.getElementById("ct106_ct107_loginview_baw_template_logincontrol_edtUsername");
var passwordField = document.getElementById("ct106_ct107_loginview_baw_template_logincontrol_edtPassword");

loginField.value = myUsername;
passwordField.value = myPassword;

var loginForm = document.getElementById ("ct106_ct107_loginview_baw_template_logincontrol_btnLogin");

loginForm.submit();
checkCookie();
```

Answer (score 0):

The "content_script" section needs to be an array of objects, because an extension can contain multiple content scripts, matching different patterns.

E.g.

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://www.bwin.com/"],
    "js": ["autofill.js"]
}],
```

Comment: Thanks Robin. I have now these problems:

Unrecognized manifest key 'all_frames'.
Unrecognized manifest key 'run_at'.
Permission 'https://www.bwin.it' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Ok, the problems I wrote down before are solved. Anyway, when I click on the button to make the code work, it doesn't do anything. Anyone can help me?